# Remote access services exposed by docker container

Tags: docker, remote-access

I wrote a simiple program which listening to tcp 9999 and udp 9966, and wrap the program into a docker container like this:

```
FROM jeanblanchard/busybox-java
ADD testprg /opt/testprg
EXPOSE 9999
EXPOSE 9966/udp
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/testprg/start.sh"]
```

And then run the docker like this:

```
docker run -d -P testprg
```

and the `docker ps -a` results (PORTS part):

```
0.0.0.0:14355->9966/udp, 0.0.0.0:14337->9999/tcp
```

Everything looks well, and I can telnet to `localhost 14337` and get response, but not from remote machine. And I've tried to use `lsof -i :14337` or `netstat -nat | grep docker`, got nothing.

I've also try to add `iptable` route like this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i 192.168.1.101 -p tcp --dport 14355 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9999
```

Also, got nothing from remote machine. So, my question is, how can I redirect the ports exposed by my program to outside of my host?

Answer (score 0):

Haha, sorry, my mistake, my remote machine is not in the same network as my host, this config works like a charm.